# Autocomplete search drop down angular

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material, angular-forms

I have a dropdown where I get some json data. I get the data through a get all API. So I havent hardcoded any data.I am doing this in angular

```html
<td>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Customer</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="custom">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customerList" [value]="customer.id">
        {{customer.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</td>
```

So here I have a List named  customerList where the data is in json format inside. So I have to display the name field at dropdown and pass the id to backend. So my task here is to do a autocomplete search on this dropdown

Comment: can you add you sample customerList, ts file and html file here?

Comment: [{"id":1,"name": "kumar"},{"id":2, "name" "mukesh"}].  I cant add ts file as its too large to comprehend

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [AutoComplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) from Angular Material.

```html
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

In your component, you can write your own filter logic something like this

```
filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

Comment: I tried the exact same thing previously. I didnt get a error and at the same time no search dropdown too. Is there any specific place the tscode should be placed? Because I have a ton of code in ts

Comment: @JoeRishwanth try again

Comment: Didnt help. No dropdown is getting displayed.

Comment: @JoeRishwanth unless you post a stackblitz link of what have you tried nobody can help you

Answer (score 0):

@Joe Rishwanth You need to add `mat-autocomplete` for dropdown

**Html file for Your customer List:**

```
<form class="example-form">
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text"
       placeholder="Enter Customer name"
       aria-label="Number"
       matInput
       [formControl]="custom"
       [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customerFilter | async" [value]="customer">
            {{customer.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Ts file:

```
export class AutocompleteAutoActiveFirstOptionExample implements OnInit {
  custom = new FormControl();
  customerList = [{ id: 1, name: "kumar" }, { id: 2, name: "mukesh" }];
  customerFilter: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerFilter = this.custom.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(""),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): any {
    const filterValue = value;
    return this.customerList.filter(customer => {
      return customer.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0;
    });
  }
}
```

Reference for stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ih4c5r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts